# Retrieve Original Input Variables From Feature Selection in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm creating a script that automates some pretty generic machine learning for some datasets. The script should be able to handle categorical and numeric data, so in my preprocessing I use `OneHotEncoder`. I also need to select a set amount amount of features in my feature selection, so I'm using RFE with an ExtraTreesClassifier. The problem arises is that the RFE selects 20 (or whatever else n_features is) of the `OneHotEncoded` features instead of original input features.

This model will be used on a web app, so I need those ~20 selected variables as input variables (meaning originally from the dataset). Is there any way to feature select input variables, like `car_color` instead of the one hot encoded ones that appear, like `x0_car_color` or an index?

Example of what I'm currently doing:

```
# train/test split 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset)

# the preprocessor
preprocessing_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))])

# preprocesses the data
x_train_pp = pd.DataFrame(preprocessing.fit_transform(x_train))
x_test_pp = pd.DataFrame(preprocessing.transform(x_test))

# the algorithm used in rfe
classifier = ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=random_seed)

# creates the rfe object
rfe_object = RFE(classifier, n_features_to_select=20)

# fits the rfe object with the x train dataset and y train series
rfe.fit(x_train_pp, y_train)

# returns the columns selected from RFE
return x_train.columns[rfe.support_]
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @desertnaut Just added it

Comment: Are you asking, if you can feature select the original attribute and not the result of the one-hot-encoding? if so, when would you like your feature reduction to remove the original attribute completely?